# How to add quests in Batch RPG

Tags: batch-file

Firstly, if there's a question asking the same thing, I'm sorry but I couldn't find it.

Well, I'm currently in the planning stages of a batch RPG. As well as storyline and all that, I'm also planning out features. One of them that I'm considering is quests, but I don't know how to put quests in the game. I asked Yahoo answers first but someone told me I'd get better answers here, so if someone can tell me how to it and maybe type up a quick example, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think your problem is at least two-fold. First, you need to know how to put quests in a game, then you'll want to find out how to code that in Windows batch scripting (if that's what you meant by *batch*). Both questions seem a bit too broad and may need to be asked separately. It's possible that someone with actual experience of batch game writing does have a good general suggestion, though.

Comment: I'm already pretty well familiarized with Batch scripting. I'd say I'm probably about mid-level skill at it. I'm just not sure how to go about writing in quests.

Comment: Just a future reference, this isn't a question suitable for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a quest in batch is nearly impossible, but for a working level-by-level RPG you need to do something like this:

```
:level1
set health=100
echo quest-level-1.
pause
goto level2

:level2
set health=80 
echo quest-level-2
if health=80 goto finish

:finish
You have completed the quest!
pause
goto start
```

This will work as a nice quest-by-quest type of thing. If you want to make it more realistic, you can add an energy bar as well.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, though you may think its hard. I'll show you my batch RPG code ( IT WONT WORK IF YOU USE IT!)

```
:questsC

 cls

if %Q% LEQ 0 goto quests
if %GQ% GEQ 1 goto GQuestC
if %PQ% GEQ 1 goto PQuestC
if %WQ% GEQ 1 goto WQuestC
if %CPQ% GEQ 1 goto CPQuestC

:quests
set GK=0
set PK=0
cls
echo Select a quest
echo.
echo 1) Kill 5 Goblins (+50 Gold!)
echo 2) Kill 5 Evil Pizzas (+75 Gold!)
echo 3) Kill 5 Wolfs (+150 Gold!)
echo 4) Kill 5 Chili Peppers (+200 Gold!)
echo 5) Go back home
set /p quest=
if %quest% == 1 goto QGS
if %quest% == 2 goto QPS
if %quest% == 3 goto QWS
if %quest% == 4 goto CPWS
if %quest% == 5 goto begin

:CPWS
set CPK=0
set CPQ=1
set Q=1
goto begin

:CPQuestC
if %CPK% GEQ 5 goto CPQuest
if %CPK% LSS 5 goto QuestCP

:QuestCP
cls
echo Quest not complete. You only have %CPK% kills.
pause
goto begin

:CPQuest
Start Levelup.mp3
cls
set CPQ=0
set /a Gold=%Gold%+200
set /a EXP=%EXP%+200
cls
echo Quest Complete! You got 200 gold and 200 exp!
pause
goto begin

:QWS
set WK=0
set WQ=1
set Q=1
goto begin

:QGS
set GK=0
set GQ=1
set Q=1
goto begin

:QPS
set PK=0
set PQ=1
set Q=1
goto begin

:GQuestC
if %GK% GEQ 5 goto GQuest
if %GK% LSS 5 goto QuestG

:WQuestC
if %WK% GEQ 5 goto WQuest
if %WK% LSS 5 goto QuestW

:WQuest
Start Levelup.mp3
cls
set WQ=0
set /a Gold=%Gold%+150
set /a EXP=%EXP%+150
cls
echo Quest Complete! You got 150 gold and 150 exp!
pause
goto begin

:QuestW
cls
echo Quest not complete. You only have %WK% kills.
pause
goto begin

:GQuest
Start Levelup.mp3
cls
set GQ=0
set /a Gold=%Gold%+50
set /a EXP=%EXP%+50
cls
echo Quest Complete! You got 50 gold and 50 exp!
pause
goto begin

:QuestG
cls
echo Quest not complete. You only have %GK% kills.
pause
goto begin

:QuestP
cls
echo echo Quest not complete. You only have %PK% kills.
pause
goto begin

:PQuestC
if %PK% GEQ 5 goto PQuest
if %PK% LSS 5 goto QuestP

:PQuest
Start Levelup.mp3
cls
set PQ=0
set /a Gold=%Gold%+75
set /a EXP=%EXP%+100
echo Quest Complete! You got 75 gold and 100 exp!
pause
goto begin
```

OK! So first it looks a Q which tells the computer if a quest is in progress. If so it checks to see which one you have. Then it checks to see if you met the requirements. Then, COMPLETE!!! Easy as pie huh? Study this code! Here's a link to my game if your interested! I also have tutorials on my youtube channel (  mineit909 ) that tells you how to make this game. Here's the game link. http://www.mediafire.com/?c87yz2hqawx43 DOWNLOAD EACH FILE!!! IF A SOUND FILE ISN'T WORKING THEN TAKE OUT THE START ( SOUND FILENAME ) IN THE CODE! PUT EVERYTHING IN THE SAME FOLDER!!!

Answer (score 0):

if %quest1% greq 1 goto questcomplete
when they complete said quest, do:

set quest1=1

:questcomplete
cls
echo yay! you did tha quest!